# How to read first five character from buffered reader?

Tags: java, android, xml, root, busybox

I have this code

```
Process p =Runtime.getRuntime().exec("busybox");
        InputStream a = p.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader read = new InputStreamReader(a);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(read);
```

Running it from the terminal the first lines of oupout return the version of Busybox. If I wanted to take for example the first 5 characters as I do?

Comment: do you want to read first five character from buffered reader?

Comment: @MariocciRossini-Just use of subString(int startposition,int endposition)...i thinks this will help u.

Answer (score 2):

While the other answers should work well too, the following will exit and close the stream after reading five characters:

```
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("busybox");
    InputStream a = p.getInputStream();
    InputStreamReader read = new InputStreamReader(a);

    StringBuilder firstFiveChars = new StringBuilder();

    int ch = read.read();

    while (ch != -1 && firstFiveChars.length() < 5) {
        firstFiveChars.append((char)ch);
        ch = read.read();
    }

    read.close();
    a.close();

    System.out.println(firstFiveChars);
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 String line = in.readLine();
 if(line!=null && line.length() >5)
     line = line.substring(0, 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this way

```
Process p;
        try {
            p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("busybox");
            InputStream a = p.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader read = new InputStreamReader(a);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(read);
            StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            try {
                while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    buffer.append(line);
                }

            } finally {
                read.close();
                in.close();
            }

            String result = buffer.toString().substring(0, 15);
            System.out.println("Result : " + result);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

**Output**

Result : BusyBox v1.13.3

Comment: should it be buffer.toString().substring(0, 5) ?